# Internet Explorer 8: list problem

Tags: html, html-lists

There is an unordered list, and one of the list items contains two links. For some reason, Internet Explorer 8 is showing the part of the list item beginning with the first link as outside the list and apparently outside the containing div also. Here is what it looks like (those two lines should be on one line!):

[Illustration of list Problem http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7726/listproblem.png](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/7726/listproblem.png)

The html:

```
<!-- These div make up the background image -->
<div class = "box">
<div class="boxBody">
    <ul>
        <li> </li>
        <li> <a href=""></a><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: square;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

EDIT: On going step by step through the code, I found that for some reason having links inside the li is what is causing the problem. Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: can u post the code & screenshot how it looks. so that I can take a look and crack whats going wrong.

Comment: Is the picture still unreadable? I can see it...

Comment: This is a presentational issue. Presentation = CSS. Where is your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...that I forgot to close a previous link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think having links inside LI can cause any issues. By any chance are you using any reset CSS? (some CSS code to reset LI, UL etc..?)